# React Redux - Finding a use case for connect()

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

Note: I'm using React Native but this applies to Reactjs also. I only use stateless functional components by design. I'm wanting to learn and use functional programming as much as possible. Does this essentially mean I can never use `connect()` from `react-redux`? Should I be adding more container components to my app design?

Here is an example of my components:

```
export const Height = (props, { store }) => {
  const state = store.getState()
  return (
    <View style={formStyles.container}>
      <DimenInput 
        value={state.get('height').get('height1').toString()}
        onChangeText={text => store.dispatch(updateHeight(text, 1))}
      />
      <Text style={formStyles.text}>{'&'}</Text>
      <DimenInput 
        value={state.get('height').get('height2').toString()}
        onChangeText={text => store.dispatch(updateHeight(text, 2))}
      />
    </View>
  )
}
Height.contextTypes = {
  store: React.PropTypes.object
}
```

I also want to learn all common redux and react techniques that I will see in the industry so I wanted to learn `mapStateToProps()` and `connect()`. I started to try and create these functions for my component above:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return state.get('height').get('height1').toString()
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    onHeightChanged: (text) => {dispatch(updateHeight(text, 1))}
  } 
}
```

Before realising that I cannot use those functions on this stateless component. I have to use them on a container component that would essentially hold this component but I don't really have one, the container of this component is:

```
export const Volcalc = () => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.text}>HEIGHT</Text>
      <Height/>
      <Text style={styles.text}>WIDTH</Text>
      <Width/>
    </View>
  )
}
```

And then the container of that is just:

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Volcalc/>
    </Provider>
  )
}
```

The app I'm making is a single form - so it is tiny. At this stage I cannot see any situation where I would HAVE to use a container component. In a larger app would I be forced to use container components and then I will get the chance to use `connect()`? Which technique is better out of using only stateless, and using a container created with `connect()`, if it could be done either way?

Edit: [this egghead lesson](https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-redux-generating-containers-with-connect-from-react-redux-addtodo) does something in between where they have a stateless component `AddTodo` that uses `dispatch` from the store and they call `connect()` on it. Possibly the scenario which would fit my use case for `Height` although I will need to keep passing it the full store since it uses `store.get` and `store.dispatch` - unless I pass it the store value for height instead of the full store.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using connect on a container component you are keeping your app functional.  Your data flows down to children.  Your state is immutable.

Container components are useful in regards to connect because you're isolating your call to the store and, again, letting data flow down to child components.  It's just a good way to structure your app and reduces the number of points the store is called in your app.  It makes development much easier to manage and presents fewer opportunities to create a mess.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use connect(), but your components will then become more tightly coupled with redux. If you have Height container and you can remove those redux store code from Height component and make it reusable easily on other non-redux project.

Comment: Definitely something to consider. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Using class as object-oriented pattern and some functional oriented patterns all mixed together makes a beautiful result. It's perfect if you want to practice your functional programming skills, but sadly, if you do so for a more serious application, you will loose a lot of benefits from react and redux. Things like state, your application will be hard to update. Your code will be coupled. and close to modifications. In a bigger application, you will find it frustrating developing it. I took the exact same path not long ago and I'm enjoying react and redux way more mixing both. This is my opinion. If you want to use connect, component state and most of the advantages of react and redux with keeping it fully functional, you can use `React.createClass()`, this is a function receiving an object with other function in it. Like instead of initializing the component state in the class constructor, you will use a function, `getInitialState` in this case. Containers are very useful to get reusable components. Another problem is passing redux props down to some components. With a small app, it's easy to pass those props not more than 3 level deep, but in a big app, it's not. Imagine, each time your redux state change, your whole app re-render and to avoid losing your data, you will have store those data in your redux state. You redux store will be too big and will contain useless data and data that shouldn't be there.

To sum up, that's perfectly fine to do a small app in full functional mode, but for a bigger app, you will loose to much react and redux benefits, making your app hard to modify and develop.

Comment: Thanks. One question regarding the issue with passing Redux props many levels down. Is that not solved by using the `Provider` which uses the "react advanced context feature"? Say I have a child component 6 levels down which maps to the store value "height", I can just add { store } to the component arguments and declare the context types as object below it so that none of the levels in between need to pass it down. If height in the store updates it should only re-render components that map to height shouldn't it?

Comment: Good point. Using react context will help to make better code, but the context is still passed down. It won't trigger the re-rendering, so you are right on this. In a case like that, I would normally suggest using shouldComponentUpdate to avoid useless re-render, but this not available in a stateless functional component. You seem to know what you are doing and I'm pretty sure there is a solution for most of the case, but maybe not and some solution might be hackish solution. You need to be careful using this path.

Answer (score 1):

It is good to see some other peoples thoughts on this because I'm coming in new. But i gather from the other answers on this question that there are some performance optimisations that `connect()` takes care of and also it is good to not pass the whole store to a component because the react advanced context feature is unstable and also it couples the component to redux when using the redux store in the component.

I have gone over the tutorials some more and realised I can use `connect()` on my stateless component giving the benefits above.

Code:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    height1: state.get('height').get('height1').toString(),
    height2: state.get('height').get('height2').toString()
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    updateHeight: (text, number) => {
      dispatch(updateHeight(text, number))
    }
  } 
}

let Height = (props) => {
  return (
    <View style={formStyles.container}>
      <DimenInput 
        value={props.height1}
        onChangeText={text => props.updateHeight(text, 1)}
      />
      <Text style={formStyles.text}>{'&'}</Text>
      <DimenInput 
        value={props.height2}
        onChangeText={text => props.updateHeight(text, 2)}
      />
    </View>
  )
}
Height.propTypes = {
  height1: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  height2: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  updateHeight: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired
}

Height = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(Height)
```